# How to group overlapping polygon features to generate unique feature ID?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst, overlapping-features, analysis

I have a group on onshore leases that are overlapping and I want to generate a field attribute so that all the polygons (or centroids of the polygons) that overlap have a unique ID so that I can filter when exported in excel?

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It can be done be done by using the intersect tool and select by location.

First step:

Use the intersect tool. When used on a single layer the output are only the parts that were overlapping.

Second step:

Use the Select by location function to select the features in your original layer and give them the uniqe number via the field calculator. (if needed the centroid overlapping can be chosen here)